# How to draw indicator lines at 30% and 70% on a half Doughnut chart

Tags: d3.js

I have a half doughnut chart below. I just want to know how can i draw 2 indicators lines, one at the 30% and the other at the 70% mark?

http://imgur.com/xkkEZIC

Thank You!

Regards,
Yee Kai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw an pieChart to achieve it.

```
.startAngle(-90 * (pi / 180))
.endAngle(90 * (pi / 180));
```

Here is an nvd3 and a pure d3 fiddle for your reference:

[nvd3 fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/33tx0ux5/3/)

[d3 fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/az7av2pv/)